# Refreshing a database or table with management tools

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio there is an option to refresh a table / database?

Is there a similar option for Oracle? If yes how do I do this? Is there a command to run to do this? Lastly what does the refresh actually do? Does it commit the latest data and break locks?

Comment: Please clarify - are you looking for an Oracle equivalent of a SQL Server tool you're familiar with?  Or are you looking for tool recommendations for both DBMSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the context menu item.

The Refresh option just means it will request the structure of the table (keys, columns, constraints, and so on) again from SQL Server. It has nothing to do with data, locks, committing changes or anything like that.

This menu option is also available for other objects (like database) in the tree view for a SQL Server database in SSMS.

Comment: Which tool in Oracle any idea?

Comment: This is really just a UI function specific to SSMS. I'm not familiar with client tools to manage Oracle instances, but I'd imagine it would be very similar. In the end the point is that "refresh" *does not* affect the database.

Comment: @user554134 - Which tool are you currently using to access Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

With SQL server you can use SQL Developer to refresh tables.